# Change value in column A when the date surpasses the date in column B, SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, azure-functions

I am currently setting up a database in SQL Server for a subscription microservice where people are able to purchase a subscription/membership. In my SQL Server database i have two columns, 'subscriptionIsValid' (bit) and 'subscriptionEnd' (datetime). I want to make it so that when the current realtime date surpasses the subscriptionEnd date, subscriptionIsValid will be set to 0.

I have looked up multiple blogs, websites etc. but i cannot seem to find an answer anywhere. I would love to know if there is a way to trigger a stored procedure or something along the lines of an Azure function when the current date surpasses a date in a column?

**EDIT**: Maybe some more background info of the architectual setup:

I have a user microservice and a subscription microservice. These services will be connected with RabbitMQ to exchange data. I need the user service to know when a subscription/membership of a user is active or not. This means the subscription service needs to know when to send that data over RabbitMQ to the user service. I think the best way to do this is to create an Azure function to call an endpoint in my subscription service to let RabbitMQ know it can send it to the user service. This function would have to be triggered when the current date surpasses the date in the column.

Comment: I've removed the [[tag:mysql]] tag, as I don't see anything about MySQL here. If your question *is* about MySQL in addition to SQL Server, then please re-add the tag, but also [edit] your question to explain how it's involved in the problem.

Comment: A Computed Column would be one option for this purpose in SQL Server.

Comment: A computed column is fine, but you can't trigger stuff based by the changes in it me thinks. Not even change tracking if i recall correctly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use a computed column. Here is how the definition of field `subscriptionIsValid` would look as a computed column:

```
[subscriptionIsValid] AS (case when [subscriptionEnd] IS NOT NULL 
    AND [subscriptionEnd] >= GETDATE() then (1) else (0) end)
```

You can change `>=` to just '>' depending on whether or not you want a subscription to end immediately on the end date, or if the end date is inclusive in the subscription.